# How to convert ‘const omnetpp::SimTime’ to ‘double’

Tags: omnet++

In OMNeT++, I want to calculate the elapsed time (in second) of a scheduled event(a) when the event is cancelled.

If I write the following code:

```
double b = simTime() - a->getSendingTime();
cancelEvent(a);
```

it shows error:

> cannot convert ‘const omnetpp::SimTime’ to ‘double’

I also tried following way:

`simtime_t b = simTime() - a->getSendingTime();`

It showed no error.

Can anyone please suggest me how to convert `simTime` to double and
which syntax right for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
simtime_t b = simTime() - a->getSendingTime();
```

add

```
double c = b.dbl();
```